# scriptaculous slideshow

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

I am trying to make a scriptaculous slideshow but I have no idea how to loop over all the images in the div tag and then check if it is the last image and assign it to the first img. I can add the fading and whatnot myself but I have no idea how to loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

How do you store the images for the slideshow? If you use arrays, then you are looking for `imageArray.length`. Also you may have a look at the [source code for lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#download), as it uses prototype and scriptacolous as well and uses arrays for storing grouped images.

In pure JavaScript you would do something this to get the images as an array included in a div with an ID:

```
getImageArray = function(containerId) {
    var containerElement = document.getElementById(containerId);
    if (containerElement) {
        var imageArray = containerElement.getElementsByTagName("img");
        return imageArray;
    } else {
        return null; // or something similar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scriptaculous is built on prototype so you can do

```
var arrayOfChildren = $('myContainerDIvId').childElements();
// myContainerDiv is the id of the parent Div.
var numberOfChildren = arrayOfChildren.length;
arrayOfChildren[numberOfChildren] will = the last child in the parent div.
```

then to loop through the children in the parent div you can do

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfChildren; i++){
  // do something with arrayOfChildren[i]
}
```